# how do you repeat the total entered?

Tags: c#

I am very new to c# and I don't get it very quickly. If you can explain how and why like your talking to a 3yr old that would be great!!!

how do you make (enter the amount (-1 to stop)) repeat and end up with a total of all amounts entered?

Comment: Little boy, get away from that PC!!

Comment: Sounds like an assignment? If you show what you have tried to do to solve it, you are much more likely to get feedback on it.

Comment: This version of your question is hardly better than [the previous one you wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207014/c-sharp-very-new-to-this-not-doing-well-how-do-you-make-enter-dollar-amount). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am new to all of this, including this site. I'm sure you were also new at one time. I'm sick of waisting 10 hours a day on this crap. The class shows nothing on how to do this, can't find crap online. My only way to get any answers is here.

Comment: • Accept the dollar value of each item purchased from the user until the user is finished.  
• When purchases are complete, enter a sentinel value of -1 (indicating that the user has finished).  
• If the item purchased is $50.00 or more, give your customer a 10% discount on the item purchased.  
• If the customer gets a discount on the item, display the original purchase price and the discounted purchase price.  Otherwise, display “No discount applied.”
• When the customer enters -1 (indicating that the user has finished), display the total cost of all items.

Comment: Console.Write("\nEnter dollar amount(-1 to stop):  ");
            while (true)
            {
                dollarValue = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (dollarValue == -1) break;
                sum = sum + dollarValue;
            }
           Console.Write("Enter your item pruchased:  ");
            itemsPurchased = Console.ReadLine();
            if (dollarValue > 50)
            {
                discount = totalPrice * .10;
                discountPrice = totalPrice - discount;
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, my 3-year old is sitting right here, so I had him write it out :)

```
var total = 0;  // This will hold the sum of all entries
var result = 0;  // This will hold the current entry

// This condition will loop until the user enters -1
while (result != -1)
{
    // Write the prompt out to the console window
    Console.Write("Enter the amount (-1 to stop): ");

    // Capture the user input (which is a string)
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    // Try to parse the input into an integer (if TryParse succeeds, 
    // then 'result' will contain the integer they entered)
    if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
    {
        // If the user didn't enter -1, add the result to the total
        if (result != -1) total += result;
    }
    else
    {
        // If we get in here, then TryParse failed, so let the user know.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid amount.", input);
    }
}

// If we get here, it means the user entered -1 and we exited the while loop
Console.WriteLine("The total of your entries is: {0}", total);
```

Answer (score 1):

We are calling it loops, little boy :P
UPDATE I dont know if i understood you, but now the code writes sum each time, and if you enter for example -5 it will be sum = sum - 5

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // thoose are variables, and they are storing data
        int input = 0; // input integer number
        int sum = 0; // sum of all numbers

        while (true) //Infinite loop (executes undereneath code until true=true)
        {
            input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // read the line from user, parse to int, save to input variable
            if (input == -1) break; // if integer input is -1, it stops looping (the loop breaks) and GOES  (two lines down)
            sum = sum+ input; // summing all input (short version -> s+=input)
            Console.WriteLine("Actual Sum: "+sum);  // HERE IS THE UPDATE
        }
          //HERE
        Console.WriteLine("Your final sum is: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i need to discount the sum and show that discount with a new total